# Collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have threes models: countries, states and cities.  Countries has_many states and states has_many cities.  When I create a new city I want to have a drop-down menu to pick the Country and State.  I am not sure how to get the Country model linked with cities.

So I have something like this on the form for creating a new city:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:country_id, Country.all, :id, :country_name)%>
```

In the city model I have:

```
 def country_id  
 end
```

That allows me to get the page.  But I cannot submit the form.  If I submit the form I get

unknown attribute: country_id

Comment: You're going to have to post your model relationships at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

in your form

```
<%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :country_name %>
```

In your model make sure u have

```
attr_accessible :country_id
```

hope this works. but again post the relationships